# Could not create program address with signer seeds when creating a token account

Tags: solana

I have a PDA and I'm trying to create a token account for it, using Solana Spl Associated Token Account(https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account):

```
let (token_account_key, token_account_key_bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&stake_info_bytes, &token_program_bytes, &mint_address_bytes], spl_associated_token_program.key);
```

Now I'm trying to create the account:

```
        let account_rent = rent.minimum_balance(Account::LEN);

        let authority_signature_seeds = [&stake_info_bytes[..32], &token_program_bytes[..32], &mint_address_bytes[..32], &[token_account_key_bump_seed]];
        let signers = &[&authority_signature_seeds[..]];

        let create_ix = create_account(
            feepayer.key, 
            token_account.key, 
            account_rent, 
            Account::LEN as u64, 
            spl_associated_token_program.key
        );

        invoke_signed(&create_ix, &[
            spl_associated_token_program.clone(),
            feepayer.clone(),
            token_account.clone()
        ], signers);
```

But I'm getting this error:

`> Program returned error: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address`

Answer (score 1):

With PDAs, your program can only "sign" for PDAs generated using its program id.  In this case, your program is using the associated token account program as the program id, when it should be using itself.  So this should become:

```
let (token_account_key, token_account_key_bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&stake_info_bytes, &token_program_bytes, &mint_address_bytes], my_program_id);
```

Using your program's id as `my_program_id`, and then you would actually use this as:

```
let create_ix = create_account(
            feepayer.key, 
            token_account.key, 
            account_rent, 
            Account::LEN as u64, 
            spl_token_program.key
        );
invoke_signed(&create_ix, &[
            feepayer.clone(),
            token_account.clone()
        ], signers);
```

Note: I'm assuming that you're trying to create a token account, which must be owned by the token program.

Otherwise, it would be possible to fake "signatures" for another program, which would be a huge security risk.  For example, associated token accounts must be signed and created by the associated token account program.